# Problem accessing GP from Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I got a problem with my DC configuration: most computers can access the GP just as they should, just one Windows Server 2003 R2 (SP2) is unable to read the policy information.

I get the following error in the event log:
*"Windows cannot access the file gpt.ini for GPO CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=Domain,DC=lan. The file must be present at the location <\Domain.lan\sysvol\Domain.lan\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini>. (The format of the specified network name is invalid. ). Group Policy processing aborted."*
(Source: Userenv, Event ID: 1058)

From this computer I can't access the share \Domain.lan\sysvol, while other computers can access it without problems.

I ran DCDiag and NetDiag on the DC, both without any errors.
What else can I do to find the source of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a name resolution problem. You don't mention what kind of error message you see when you say you "can't access the share \Domain.lan\sysvol".

What does an "nslookup domain.lan" command run from a command prompt give you? You should get back a list of the IP addresses of your domain controller computers.

You've double-checked the DNS servers specified on this client to see that it's only referring to one or more domain controllers running DNS servers (i.e. no ISP DNS servers specified, etc)?

Comment: Uhm, I just checked for updates, found a few "optional updates", and after installation now it works.
Dang. I should have installed them one by one, to know which one it was.

Thanks nonetheless!